# Syntax error in print using Visual Studio code Python 3.8.5

Tags: python-3.x

Why does it show me syntax error at line 8?

```
Places = ['Giappone','Germania','Russia','Kazakistan','Inghilterra']

print("Ordine Originale")

print (Places)

print("\nOrdine Alfabetico")

print (sorted(Places))

print ("\nOrdine alfabetico inverso")

print (sorted(Places,reverse=True)

print ("\nAncora nell ordine originale")

print (Places)
```

Comment: Hi @Cetriolino, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is unclear and has been flagged. Please take a look at [How to ask a good question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `)` on line 8

It should be

```
print(sorted(Places,reverse=True))
```